# Limit defined at (x,y) = (0,0)

Tags: partial-derivative

Show that the partial derivatives of $f$ are defined when $(x,y)=(0,0)$

for $f(x,y)=\frac {2x^2y^3}{x^4+y^6}$ when $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$,
and $f(x,y)=0$ when $(x,y)=(0,0)$

I don't know how to use the limit definition of the partial derivatives to show this...

I have $\dfrac{\partial f(x,y)} {\partial x}=lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h}$. Where do I go from here?

$\dfrac{\partial f(0,0)} {\partial x} = lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}$

Is that correct?

Comment: Write down the definition for $\partial f \partial x(0,0).$

Comment: the limit definition I gave, is that not the definition of the partials?

Comment: Do it for $(0,0)!$

Comment: As I edited it above?

Comment: OK, I"m not sure what the problem is. You have a formula for $f(x,y),$ right?

Comment: Yes, so for $f(h,0)$ I use the formula for when $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$?  The problem is we get $y=0$ which puts $f(h,0)$ to $0$ also?

Comment: @jimbobeanz: How is that a problem? You get $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{0-0}h$ which is pretty easy to evaluate.

Comment: So the fact that we get $\frac{0}{h}$ shows it's defined? and its value is $0$?